# Sql работа с таймером

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Добрый день надо реализовать такой скрипт.Есть таблица в ней есть колонка статус по деффалту она оффлайн .При обращении он становится онлайн .Но мне надо через определенный срок времени сделать его оффлайн снова .то-есть вернуть деффолтовое значение или переписать.Как с этим быть?какие способы есть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно сравнивать по дате последней активности:

1) Обновляем запись в БД с последней датой активности в тот момент, когда пользователь что-либо делает.

2) При получении списка онлайн юзеров сравниваем, что дата последней активности не старше чем текущая дата
+ определенный промежуток времени, после которого юзер считается в оффлайне (например 5 минут).